# Not able to find Calender Tools on sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I am new to sharepoint development. I wanted to integrate my projects SP calendar to my outlook client. I saw couple of demos where they showed to use calendar tools on SP but I am not able to find calendar tools on my SP site.

Can you please help?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Within the calendar actions, you can find a "Connect to Outlook" function.  Where to look for it depends on your version of SharePoint.  In 2010 and before, it's in the "Actions" menu.  In 2013 (and I think 2016 and Online) it's in the ribbon on the "Calendar" tab.